# How do you make text vertical in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I want to make a text look like this:

```
S
u
p
e
r

U
s
e
r
```

I can go to a new line after each letter, but it's not really practical. Where can I find the setting to make the text be written in a vertical way in Word 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Enter your [Word art](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/WordArt-Tools-eb0e6ddc-d9ff-4d4a-859f-fa28e5ad2d00) as usual
- Then click on the word art box you just made
- Make sure you click on 'Format' on the top of Publisher
- Third option across the top says 'vertical text'
- Click and your text is vertical ;)

Comment: but those texts will have a lot of effects applied and you can't edit it easily like text in a textbox or Excel sheet

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a setting for that specifically but you can make a text box, type in the text box and then re-size the box so it is narrow enough to only allow for one letter per line. It will automatically push letters to the next line as the box narrows.

Comment: Indeed, it's not the ideal solution, but it's already a better workaround than changing line myself after each letter.

Comment: You can also do the same with tables, but in general I think the text boxes are easier to work with for this type of formatting.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an answer how to easy make vertical text in word 2010 or 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Excel does have a [format option for that](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rotate-or-align-text-in-a-cell-8bf8177a-d2e8-4f5c-a707-d51625fd7758), so you can **insert an Excel spreadsheet** to the Word file instead, by going to *Insert tab > Table > Excel Spreadsheet*

[image: word new excel spreadsheet]

After that right click the cell that contains the text you want to rotate > *Format cells* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) then change the text orientation as below

[image: text direction]

Or you can simply click the *Orientation* button on Home/Alignment and select *Vertical Text*

[image: vertical text]

By default there are no borders between cells, so it'll be blank when printing even though you can see them being grey *on screen* (just like how Excel works by default). But if you also need the page to be blank *on screen* then you can edit the cells' *fill color* to white (in the same *Format cells* dialog above) which results in a word file like this

[image: blank word file]

Comment: Indeed, it works this way, and you actually have control over the orientation, you don't just hope you made a cell thin enough. Nice idea.

Comment: yeah you can resize the table or cell to fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

Use Word's *Find and Replace* along with regular expressions.

1. Enter the text you want displayed vertically as a single string (no spaces).
2. Open Find and Replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
3. Select the **Use wildcards** check box. If you don't see **Use wildcards** check box, click **More**.
4. Enter the following:

   **Find what:** `([A-Za-z])`

   **Replace with:** `\1^`
5. Click **Replace All**. A line break will be inserted after each upper and lower case letter.

Below is a quick description of this regular expression.

- `()` round brackets group and capture matched text
- `[]` square brackets enclose a character class, in this case all upper and lower case letters, `A-Za-z`
- `\1` is a backreference to Group 1 matched in the find expression

Word's regular expressions differ from standard regex in some ways, and more information about using regular expressions in Word can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Format table direction]

This may be the answer you are looking for.

Comment: This is simply rotating the whole text rather than leaving it horizontal with one character per line.

Comment: No, I'm looking for vertical text, with the letters keeping their normal orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way this can be done while keeping the text vertical is using a Word Art Box.

Insert Tab then Word Art

Answer (score 0):

Try making the right indent on your paragraph format larger than the paragraph width. This should force the text to a single letter per line.

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score -2):

Go to Insert and then insert table.  The Table Tools will appear and go to Layout.  In the Alignment section you will find Text Direction.  Under Text Direction you can do what you are looking to do.

Comment: This is the same as Curious Apprentice's solution above. It rotates all the text, including character orientation