# Typing vertically in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I registered just moments ago, so I do apologise if this question has been asked and answered already, in which case would someone please redirect me!

I need to know, ASAP, how to type words in 'vertical' direction in Word 2013. Ideally, it is for labels for folder spines. My only option at the minute is to use Word 2013.

Is there any kind citizen out there willing to talk/walk me through this (in simple speak, please)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Excel's text direction option](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/align-or-rotate-text-in-a-cell-8bf8177a-d2e8-4f5c-a707-d51625fd7758?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) by **inserting an Excel spreadsheet** to the Word file. Just select *Insert > Table > Excel Spreadsheet*

[image]

Type the text then click the *Orientation* button and select the appropriate menu item (vertical text or rotated vertical text)

[image: Orientation button]

Alternatively right click on the cell > *Format cells* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) and you'll have more text direction options

[image: text direction]

See also [How do you make text vertical in Word 2010?](https://superuser.com/q/470479/241386)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert vertical text in a table cell or using a textbox.

**Table**:

1. Insert a table. It can be a large table or just 1x1 if you only need one label. If you don't want borders printed you can remove them later.
2. Type your text in a cell.
3. With your cursor in the cell, under `Table Tools` click the `Layout` tab and then the `Text Direction` button. Your text will switch to vertical.

**Textbox**:

1. On the `Insert` tab click `Textbox` and insert a textbox.
2. Type your text.
3. With your cursor in the textbox, under `Drawing Tools` click the `Format` tab and then choose one of the `Rotate` options under `Text Direction`.

Comment: Well, thank you for that very swift answer, however that types the 'word' as a unit vertcally but no the letters. I want to be able to say.... read the word COURIERS starting with C (as you see it here) then underneath that the O and underneath that the U etc. etc. etc.

Comment: If it's such a short text, why not just type each letter in a row (and adjust the line spacing)?

Comment: Yes, I had thought of that, but there are around 25 folders to do some of which have titles the full length of the spine. I'm sure there must be a way of doing so, however, it probably necessitates purchasing software which my department will not be happy to pay for. If you have any further inspiration do please let me know.

Comment: If you can use Excel it's much easier there, since you can set vertical orientation to a cell. If Excel is an option I'll add a detailed explanation to the answer above.